# accessing array in a nested data structure containing objects and arrays with unknown property names

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-manipulation

I have the following nested object with objects and arrays :

```
'ecommerce': {
  '[dynamicvalue]': {
    'actionField': {'step': 4},
    'products': [{
        'name': 'Spirit Pack',  
        'id': '12345',
        'price': '55',
   }]
 }
```

I'd like to extract the product array however I don't know the second property name, it's a dynamic value changing all the time.

Normally I should be able to do something like this `var x = ecommerce.[dynamicvalue].products`

However since I never know this second value how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the `Object.values` of `ecommerce` to get an array of every subobject (thereby skipping the "dynamicvalue"), and then you can do what you need to with that subobject's `products`:

```js
const obj = {
  'ecommerce': {
    '[dynamicvalue]': {
      'actionField': {
        'step': 4
      },
      'products': [{
        'name': 'Spirit Pack',
        'id': '12345',
        'price': '55',
      }]
    }
  }
};

const [{ products }] = Object.values(obj.ecommerce);
console.log(products);
```

Comment: Do you have an alternative without using const?

Comment: Feel free to use `let` or `var` instead, but `const` should really be preferred when possible - it makes code easier to reason about when you *know* a variable isn't going to be reassigned.